# Combining two functions for Asciimatics and winsound

Tags: python

I found a interesting asciimatics firework on github written by peterbrittain (https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics/blob/master/samples/fireworks.py)  that I wanted to combine winsound with. I tried to create two functions and use subprocess module to execute both cuncurrently, but was not successful. I want both to start at the same time and start again together when spacebar is pressed.

```
import winsound, time

def anthem():
    winsound.Beep(391, 300)
    winsound.Beep(329, 300) 
    winsound.Beep(261, 600) 
    winsound.Beep(329, 600) 
    winsound.Beep(391, 600) 
    winsound.Beep(523, 900)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with winsound, but assuming those are blocking calls to `Beep`you need to run them in a separate thread (as per your previous question on SO).  You just need to start that thread at the right time - which would be inside the `reset()` method of your `Scene`.